# How i could check if a value exist in any row of a specific column of a specific mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to check with a script if a value exist inside the DB.
The value is based on a variable and the field is a LONGTEXT.

```
// ...:::BEGIN REGISTRATION:::...

//Add key format for hikashop
$pay = "PayPal transaction id: $pay";

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($dbo);
if (!$link)
  {
  die('Could not connect');
  }

// check if Transaction ID is available on the default website.
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM jh23m_hikashop_history WHERE history_data = '$pay'");
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $result;

// Verifica che esiste almeno una riga contente la transazione. 
// Se si procedi con la response e salva nel db, altrimenti rispondi che la key non è stata trovata.
if ($result == 0){
    die ('Your transaction has not been found. Please enter your payment transaction correctly or contact the support');
}
```

What is strange is that some value are find, but many not! 
The $pay come from a $_POST and i added $pay = "PayPal transaction id: $pay"; to make it formatted as the shop site make.

Pls HelP!

Edit: i made a part of code, tring to see why this not matches.
This is the result via ARRAY:
Array ( [0] => [1] => 0JW61238FU6854240 [2] => 5EA00979GC149044V [3] => 59P88560S9783170B [4] => 1L697134B06956638 [5] => 1N476458GR470922M [6] => 3N4412142S083993R [7] => 2GN69713EV7294613 [8] => 9WT48148YE725931K [9] => 585690586Y6998523 [10] => 7X9149767T051513K [11] => 5WJ25963L5455313H [12] => 1L717841BA5989748 [13] => 0E750230DV1575308 [14] => 85B43558SH819711N [15] => 78R85507FR2081540 [16] => 96F7363575285431M [17] => 87V99180GV2251342 [18] => 4G459145SE959020V [19] => 86U00726DL9205244 [20] => 70820350T9653825F [21] => 8K002091YN0079914 [22] => 8SD993824R7167708 [23] => 93L886231K973983G [24] => 6E98077468505954G [25] => 770172708D596892K [26] => 22N679682U615734D [27] => 3WR4000656945550Y [28] => 59P88560S9783170B [29] => 8H242117S01162917 [30] => 9WC47475K89394047 [31] => 83L6687699339330K [32] => 1BE09674W4880373N [33] => 3JC01978GH9146509 [34] => 31381161BJ159335S [35] => 17V97629HJ1941344 [36] => 4XG15144CK988864F [37] => 18625833YF123353H [38] => 2GU86013NN2703635 ) Does not matco0JW61238FU6854240

I tried this kind of script to see why:

```
// check if Transaction ID is available on the default website.
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM jh23m_hikashop_history");
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))) {
    $paypal_ids[] =$row['history_data'];
}
//print_r ($paypal_ids);
// ora cerca il valore %pay
$paypal_ids_split = implode("", $paypal_ids);
//print_r ($paypal_ids_split);
$paypal_ids_clean = explode ("PayPal transaction id: ", $paypal_ids_split);
print_r ($paypal_ids_clean);

if (in_array($pay, $paypal_ids_clean)){
    echo "Match";
} else 
{ echo "Does not matco";
}
echo $pay;
```

It still does not match? WTF?

But if i use this it matches!! WTF?
Match : 59P88560S9783170B

Is possible that some bytes are making it dirty?

Comment: have you done this, mysql_fetch_array($result);?

Comment: I think that the unique possibility is that $pay some times not match with your values and return 0,  @anilCSE with mysql_num_rows($query) is enough...

Comment: BTW some of the rows of inside DB are empty, could be a problem Emilio?

Comment: You will have to show what is in jh23m_hikashop_history.history_data on you database, and what is in the $pay.

Comment: This is making me fool! : (

Comment: Added some stuff to see how i can solve...

Answer (score 0):

I had this saved from a post I found on this issue a while ago.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Then you can switch back to numeric with MYSQL_NUM or both with MYSQL_BOTH

Comment: Seems to not work. I'm sure that im having problems not with the code itself but with the data fields. Since one of them is taken by the script, because i probabily added it manually. Instead the others, wich are added by hikashop software may are different... There is any find to say "check if this $value is present on this field?" not to extactly match?

Comment: I've seen that the sofware i try to integrate is using : ob_get_clean when saving. This could compromise matching of the string?